# Product of a normal distribution and an exponential distribution?

Tags: distributions

I am trying to find the **product of normal distribution and Exponential distribution** (Both are independent). Could we do analytically?

This question is linked with [Link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892627/product-distribution-of-independent-normal-and-exponential-random-variables), and [Link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295548/analytical-solution-of-product-of-normal-distribution-and-exponential-distributi). But still not yet answered.

Comment: Welcome to MMA StackExchange. This question doesn't seem to be related to the software Mathematica? Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: Wolfram is unable to find this one$f(z)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\lambda}{x\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{\lambda z}{x}}$.

Comment: Mathematica finds PDF[TransformedDistribution[
  x*y, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], 
   y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]]}], t] in terrms of MeijerG function $$\frac{\lambda  G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(\frac{t^2 \lambda ^2}{8 \sigma ^2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,0,\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{2 \sqrt{2} \pi  \sigma } .$$ There are wishes and there is reality.

Comment: @user64494 I am sorry, I don't know, how to change above integration function in to Meijer G function. Do we analytically change into Meijer G function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @user64494 Why do you impose the mean of the Normal distribution to be 0? The question appears to be about a general Normal distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

distx = NormalDistribution[0, σ];

disty = ExponentialDistribution[λ];

assume = DistributionParameterAssumptions[distx] &&
  DistributionParameterAssumptions[disty]

(* σ > 0 && λ > 0 *)

(cdf[z_] = 
   Probability[
    x*y <= z, {x \[Distributed] distx, 
     y \[Distributed] disty}]) //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
(pdf[z_] = Assuming[assume, D[cdf[z], z]]) //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The expressions for `z < 0` and `z > 0` are identical

```
Assuming[assume,
 Equal @@ (Simplify[pdf[z], #] & /@ {z < 0, z > 0}) //
  Simplify]

(* True *)
```

Consequently, simplify the expression to

```
(pdf[z_] = Simplify[pdf[z], z > 0]) //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
distz = TransformedDistribution[x*y,
   {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, σ],
    y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[λ]}];

(pdf2[z_] = PDF[distz, z]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Although it is difficult to show that the expressions for the `PDF` are equivalent, the numeric difference between the two expressions is zero:

```
Plot[pdf[z] - pdf2[z] /. {σ -> λ}, {z, -4, 4},
 PlotRange -> {-10^-6, 10^-6},
 WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice to see that MMA pulls this off. Springer showed that such a product is a MeijerG function back in the 70s...